# Forming adjectives via suffixes, exhaustive approach

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

My word is for postfixes (they call them suffixes) forming adjectives, very often I face missing English counterparts speaking of rich in adjectives (they are formed easily with almost no snobbish overhead i.e. 'censorship') Bulgarian language.

One of my wishes is **to have all such postfixes** in order to ease getting the whole picture while offering some useful statistical 'guidance'. Thus the brevity (one word) would be more expressive as well, not to mention the ?ringiness?.
For example, very often I struggle to find the English counterparts (both noun and adjective ones) to 'zvutchen/zvutchnost' and I use non-established 'ringy/ringiness' after the notion of:
***have a ring to it*** - if a word or idea has a ring to it, it sounds interesting or attractive

Please, share with me/us a book or an Internet page dealing exhaustively with 'adjective forming'.
I found a good Internet resource (http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj-forms.html) on this theme, but it doesn't exhaust the matter, **I need as full as possible list of those postfixes**!

Good leads to good, one beautiful unknown to me word popped up there:
***Adjectivalization*** – in linguistics, the forming of words from other categories , nouns and verbs, by suffixation. (Huddleston 1706).

Shown forms:

**-AL**     relating to

**-ARY**  relating to quality or place

**-FUL**  full of

**-IC**  having the nature of; caused by

**-ICAL**  having the nature of

**-ISH**  origin, nature

**-LESS**  without

**-LIKE**  like

**-LY**  like

**-OUS**  quality, nature

**-Y**  like

On a '-Y' note, in many TV series I hear marginal (almost invalid) coinages as 'sciency' (stands for science+Y) encountered in 'Stargate Atlantis', there the military guy said 'This guy doesn't look sciency to me.' referring to one who pretended to be from scientific community.

My add-on includes:

**-AN** e.g. BulgariAN, NewtoniAN

**-ESQUE** e.g. Hollywoodesque

**-ID** e.g. demonoID

**-AR** e.g. lineAR

**-ORY** e.g. derogatORY

-ESE e.g. tabloidESE - (neologism, chiefly literature) The writing style of tabloid
journalism.

**-ESE** e.g. DublinESE - The dialect spoken in Dublin.

For some reason Wiktionary omitted the adjectival usage, they define the above two as nouns only!?

We have 'NewtoniAN' while 'NewtonESQUE' is kinda marginal but still has its place.

Also we have 'HitleriAN' and 'HitlerESQUE', however it is difficult for me to discern, they appear fully interchangeable to me.

In Russian and Bulgarian '-ESQUE' counterpart is '-SKI', these forms are widely used, for above pair the second dominates, namely 'Гитлеровская/Хитлеристка'.

English Wiktionary says for first:
*Of, relating to, or resembling Hitler (the German chancellor) or his actions.*

English Wiktionary says for second:
"Reminiscent of Adolf Hitler."

Ha, one adjective eludes me, how to form a/the adjectival form of tweet/twitter?
First being the object second being the subject, what are the well coined variants!

**What else adjectivalizationAL forms are missing from above list?!**

Oh, just looked up for 'blackadder' adjective:

*"A striking vision of artistic compromise, personal sacrifice and political brutality, rendered in what is often a somewhat Blackadderish style."– Evening Standard*

*"In any case, the narrative of this novel blisters along with a Blackadderish cunning." /'Memoirs of a Gnostic Dwarf' book/*

*"It's recognisably Blackadderish in its approach to history, silly and inventive and with a good line in visual gags."– independent.co.uk*

*"Is Roland Emmerich's Blackadderish romp about the real author of Shakespeare's plays also a piece of post-structuralist genius?"– theguardian.com*

It turns out that British newspapers use it to/for a good measure.

Also, couldn't resist not to look into Google Books corpus (2013 edition) featuring 7,477,257 distinct words:
*[&blackadder&] 0,000,046   blackadder /Google_Books_corpus_version_20130501_English_All_Nodes.txt.rip1gram.txt.sorted/
[&blackadder&] 0,000,008    blackadders /Google_Books_corpus_version_20130501_English_All_Nodes.txt.rip1gram.txt.sorted/*

Confusing, such richness (3.5 million English books, 345 billion words corpus spanning a 200+ years period) and lacking the beautiful 'Blackadderish'.

To summarize, **which (grammar) books/resources explaining the suffixes to their fullest you can recommend?**

Add-on, 2018-Jun-25:

Scary, 3 years and 5 months passed already!

Yet, my obsession remains, glad to share my latest Suffixes-Showdown-Booklet in PDF, 2 pages long and **322 suffixes strong**:

http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postsm1048533_Etymology-of--dragon-.aspx#1048533

Hope, the feedback (both destructive and constructive) from StackExchange community will help in refining it!

Comment: Asking for a possibly infinite list is not something we allow here, so I have removed it from the question.

Comment: @MattЭллен Didn't get you.

*>What else adjectivalizationAL forms are missing from above list?!*

With above question (deleted now) I asked for more suffixes that I am unaware of, what do you mean by infinite list?
Aren't they few dozens at max?!

Comment: Even a few dozen is too many. But I believe that it's possible to make suffixes from parts of words. Such suffixes are not currently recorded in dictionaries, but would be plausible in spoken English. It is possible that a comprehensive list of suffixes that would be found in dictionaries would be useful at [ell.se] but not here.

Comment: What you ask would not solve the multitudinous single word requests in the related column. They are not looking to understand suffixes, they want a word for a particular porpoise. Would you be satisfied if I migrated the question to ELL (with the part I took out reinstated)?

Comment: The quote "Adjectivalization – in linguistics, the forming of words from other categories, nouns and verbs, by suffixation. (Huddleston 1706)" is questionable on two counts. First, calling such forming "adjectivalization" sounds dubious. Second, what is "Huddleston 1706"? Who is this Huddleston? I know of Rodney Huddleston who is one of the authors of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), but I don't know of a linguist named Huddleston who live in 1706. Maybe they meant page 1706, but they should've written it as "Huddleston 2002, p. 1706" or something similar.

Comment: BTW, I know that it's not your fault. By searching for "the forming of words from other categories , verbs and nouns, by suffixation. (Huddleston 1706)" on Google, I found what I believe is your source. On that site, they have two quotes, one of "adjectivalization" and one for "nomalization", and both are defined as exactly the same thing, that string. PS. I also tried searching for "adjectivalizationAL" and it gave me exactly one result: this page.

Comment: @DamkerngT. That was my attempt to adjectivize it, he-he. Seriously, the thing that strikes me when asking questions is how different the people's points of view are. To me, the most interesting thing is to offer a method for easy screening when one user needs the derivatives of one word, by using simple C programs fed with useful patterns (in-here suffixes).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exhaustive list, but let me give it the old college try. In english, the following suffixes are considered adjective-forming:

***Relational Family***

All the members of this family mean of or pertaining to. Some have a different scope than others.

- -al (Fungal, Cranial)
- -an/-ian/-n (Roman, American, Historian)
- -ar (Scalar, Modular)
- -ic (Acidic, Idyllic)
- -id (Perseid)
- -ese/-ish :: of or pertaining to characteristics of a location, its people, and the language they use (Japanese, Maltese, British, English, Irish)
- -ish/-y :: somewhat, about or approximately when used with numbers, typical or similar to (Sciencey, Girlish, Tennish, Twentyish)
- -ous/-ious/-atous (Bulbous, Courageous)
- -otic (Eukaryotic, Symbiotic)

***Of Similar Form To, But Not the Same As***

- -oid (Humanoid, Alkaloid)
- -like (Lifelike, Childlike)

***Others***

- -th :: ordinal (Fourth, Fifth, Sixth, Seventh, Eighth, Ninth)

Comment: Thanks, wanted to vote up but no enough rep points, grmbl.
From my standpoint, your list adds two more postfixes -TH, -LIKE. To me -*OUS are all the same since my search will be anyway for ***ous**. To me each and every postfix is dear, it opens the possibility for easy enriching of one particular wordlist with words (with specific postfix) from another wordlist. For example I made 74 pages with new words in this way, the second wordlist was MW dictionary with its built-in wildcard search. How about -AD, -PLE, -WISE as in **monAD**, **triPLE**, **speedWISE**? I wonder how many left unlisted!

Comment: Recently I asked -AD, -PLE related question:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222154/what-are-the-words-for-sets-of-n-grams-or-n-cores
I am fond of such numerals, how much more expressive is to start a sentence with: *Hexadecad-threaded tool is in use.* instead of *16-threaded tool is in use.*, yes? Somehow starting a sentence with a number is not right in my eyes.

Comment: Just saw your profile, in case of you being interested in biggest known to me English wordlist you can see my compilation called called 'Goyathlay' featuring 656,563 distinct words at:
http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/profile696240.aspx

Comment: The suffix -wise turns words into adverbs. The suffix -ad turns words into nouns. And while the suffix -ple can be used on adjectives, it doesn't form adjectives from other words. I was simply doing as OP asked and listing only the adjective-forming suffixes.

Comment: What about MW, Main Entry: **battlewise**  
Function:adjective : having knowledge of or experience in battle *battlewise troops*; Main Entry: **monad**  
Function:adjective : of the nature of a monad; Also **monadIC**; Also **monadAL**; Also **monadICAL**

Comment: While battlewise as you use it may be colloquially understood, I am under the impression that the correct way to state that would be battle-wise (wise in the ways of battle). As a single word, **battlewise** would be an adverb noting the reference to battle, not wise to it. And I'm unsure of how calling something monad would be an adjective. To my ears, using monad as an adjective would be the same as "That man has an ox jaw" instead of "That man has an ox-like jaw" which are two completely different things.

Comment: Now that I think about it, perhaps you are getting confused with a habit of english speakers to use a proper noun as an adjective, such as "That was rather Simon Cowell of you" where *Simon Cowell* is standing in for the word *harsh* or *mean* in this case.

Comment: As I said I am in search for the entire plentifulness of words, not for the restricted (widely accepted) ones. One word may be used only one time in some obscure text, it is enough for me to grab it. You may try Google Books:
1] *They were driven back (August 16) by the numerically superior Serbian army, inadequately equipped but **battlewise** from their Balkan Wars experience...* 2] *...and so were likely to meet **battlewise** veterans while they themselves were still novices.*

Comment: As for 'monad' and using compound nouns:
*The unity of the Godhead is such that the work of each is the work of all, and therefore the worship of each is the worship of all.  Christians do not serve **a monad person** as deity; but the God of heaven and earth is revealed as existing in a trinity of Persons.  The attempted exclusion of any one or more Persons of the Godhead in worship is to profane the worship entirely.  God, in the fullness of the divine essence, is to be worshipped.*  That's why I hold dear words as monad/dyad/triad.

Comment: 1] *... angles to usher them to their Real-Nature (absolute reality, peace and bliss) from the realm of their apparent nature, which is their jivahood or monadhood.* 
2] *A monad which becomes buddha simply re-enters its own monadhood; or to speak in the technical language of the Mahayana Buddhist philosophy, the buddha ...*
3] *This theory has the disadvantages of practically denying the independence of mind from body and of separating monadhood from selfhood.*
We have godhead/godhood/selfhood/monadhood,
god**LY** (an adverb as well) self**ISH** and monadIC/monadAL, funny how postfixes vary.

Answer (score 1):

- **-ed** (the past tense of a verb can usually be used as an adjective.)
- **-ible** (use with words that you can add -ion to.)  For example:  combustion -> combustible.
- **-able** (use with words that you cannot add -ion to, such as words that you can add -ation to.)  For example:  find -> findable, commiserate -> miserable.
- **-ile**  (Only use with words that you can add -ion to.)  For example:  projection -> projectile.
- **-ive** (Only use with words that you can add -ion to.)  For example:  motion -> motive.
- **-ative** (Only use with words that you can add -ation to.)  For example: formation -> formative.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, your needy add-ons will reinforce my postfix searches.
How did I miss such major ones as -ible/-able/-ile!
abaxile
germanophile (noun/adjective)
glissile
senile

Comment: Also -ive, as in abrasive.
Also -able, as in abominable.
Your add-on is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*-ID e.g. demonoID* is wrong, and should be -OID. HumanOID, FelinOID, DemonOID. ...for that matter, it may need to be -nOID -- i.e., I can't think of a time to use -oid without an N-sound in the word before it (minus any silent E). Feline, felinoid. Human, humanoid.

Comment: Thanks, 'felinoid' - I like that. You see, having those suffixes along with extensive (exhaustive is the neverending goal) adjectival list is the whole point, my needs are far greater than one 'normal' user would ... use. The goal is to have them beforehand not when the time is short and usually the user starts asking "Where is that manual/list now?" I am doing my best to put all English words under one roof and then to apply some wildcard filters in order to screen the sought words.

Comment: As for the silent 'E', I made a search for ***OID** into wordlist worth 350,000+ words, there are:
acalephoid, android, adamantoid, ameboid, zomboid...

Comment: ...I had forgotten android wasn't its own word. (Thanks, Star Wars! I didn't remember these *were* the 'droids I was looking for!) So yeah, -OID in general.

Comment: Then there's Alkaloid (base-like), Asteroid (star-like), Cardioid (heart-like), Ovoid (egg-like), etc...

Comment: ...I cannot believe I forgot all these. Obviously whatever was in my head was *only* brainoid and not an actual brain. >_>